# OpenCV - Setting higher amout of threaded video streams causes streams to disconnect

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, opencv, networking

I'm trying to setup a multi video stream processing program that has simultaneusly 16 video streamings open at the same time.

When I open the 16 video streams at the same time the VideoGet Thread starts to read Empty frames.
If I only open 6 streams it works perfectly.
I have each camera on a different **thread**, and each event verification on another thread over the main thread that reads on the camera thread frame and copies it.

This is the VideoGet Thread.

```
class VideoGet:
    """
    Class that continuously gets frames from a VideoCapture object
    with a dedicated thread.
    """
    def __init__(self, idcam,ipcamara, user, passwd,resolucionh,resolucionw):
        self.stream = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://"+user+":"+passwd+"@"+ipcamara)
        self.id = idcam
        self.ip = ipcamara
        self.user = user
        self.passwd = passwd
        self.stream.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,resolucionw)
        self.stream.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,resolucionh)
        self.stream.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_AUTOFOCUS, 0)
        (self.grabbed, self.frame) = self.stream.read()
        self.stopped = False
        self.Q =[]
        self.scale_percent = 50

    def start(self):
        Thread(target=self.get, args=()).start()
        return self

    def get(self):
        i = 0
        while True:
            try:
                (self.grabbed, preFrame) = self.stream.read()
                self.width = int(preFrame.shape[1] * self.scale_percent / 100)
                self.height = int(preFrame.shape[0] * self.scale_percent / 100)
                dim = (self.width, self.height)
                self.frame = cv2.resize(preFrame, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
                if(len(self.Q) >= cfg['config']['tiempoPre']):
                    self.Q.pop(0)
                    self.Q.append(self.frame)
                else:
                    self.Q.append(self.frame)
            except Exception as e:
                i = i +1
                if(i >= 50):

                    print('Reinicializando camara: '+str(self.id))
                    self.stream = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://"+self.user+":"+self.passwd+"@"+self.ip)
                    i=0
```

I've checked the network and it seems fine.
When I watch the console I see some FFMPEG errors. [Console feed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLE66.png)

The specs of the server are:

- Intel Xeon Silver 4100 CPU 2.1Ghz
- 32GB of RAM 2666Mhz

Edit: As suggested by Christoph, I've tried to open the video streams with FFMPEG only and this is the output.

```
C:\Users\Administrator>ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i "rtsp://admin:Instalador20@
172.20.0.7" -i "rtsp://admin:Instalador20@172.20.0.8" -i "rtsp://admin:Instalado
r20@172.20.0.9" -i "rtsp://admin:Instalador20@172.20.0.10" -i "rtsp://admin:Inst
alador20@172.20.0.11" -i "rtsp://admin:Instalador20@172.20.0.12" -i "rtsp://admi
n:Instalador20@172.20.0.13" -i "rtsp://admin:Instalador20@172.20.0.14" -i "rtsp:
//admin:Instalador20@172.20.0.15" -i "rtsp://admin:Instalador20@172.20.0.16" -fi
lter_complex "nullsrc=size=3840x720 [base]; [base][0:v] overlay [tmp]; [tmp][1:v
] overlay=x=1280" video.mp4
ffmpeg version git-2019-10-13-4f4334b Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg develop
ers
  built with gcc 9.2.1 (GCC) 20191010
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfi
g --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libb
luray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enab
le-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --e
nable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable
-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 -
-enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enab
le-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --en
able-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcode
c --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 -
-enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf
  libavutil      56. 35.100 / 56. 35.100
  libavcodec     58. 59.102 / 58. 59.102
  libavformat    58. 33.100 / 58. 33.100
  libavdevice    58.  9.100 / 58.  9.100
  libavfilter     7. 62.100 /  7. 62.100
  libswscale      5.  6.100 /  5.  6.100
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://admin:Instalador20@172.20.0.7':
  Metadata:
    title           : Media Presentation
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.200667, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main), yuv420p(progressive), 1280x720, 30 fps, 30
tbr, 90k tbn, 60 tbc
[udp @ 0000004c83b49dc0] 'circular_buffer_size' option was set but it is not sup
ported on this build (pthread support is required)
[udp @ 0000004c8412ae80] 'circular_buffer_size' option was set but it is not sup
ported on this build (pthread support is required)
Input #1, rtsp, from 'rtsp://admin:Instalador20@172.20.0.8':
  Metadata:
    title           : Media Presentation
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.316000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #1:0: Video: h264 (Main), yuv420p(progressive), 1280x720, 20 fps, 30
tbr, 90k tbn, 40 tbc
[udp @ 0000004c83c0fd40] 'circular_buffer_size' option was set but it is not sup
ported on this build (pthread support is required)
[udp @ 0000004c83c0f9c0] 'circular_buffer_size' option was set but it is not sup
ported on this build (pthread support is required)
Input #2, rtsp, from 'rtsp://admin:Instalador20@172.20.0.9':
  Metadata:
    title           : Media Presentation
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.317000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #2:0: Video: h264 (Main), yuv420p(progressive), 1280x720, 20 fps, 30
tbr, 90k tbn, 40 tbc
[udp @ 0000004c83c0f480] 'circular_buffer_size' option was set but it is not sup
ported on this build (pthread support is required)
[udp @ 0000004c84337d00] 'circular_buffer_size' option was set but it is not sup
ported on this build (pthread support is required)
Input #3, rtsp, from 'rtsp://admin:Instalador20@172.20.0.10':
  Metadata:
    title           : Media Presentation
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.317000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #3:0: Video: h264 (Main), yuv420p(progressive), 1280x720, 20 fps, 30
tbr, 90k tbn, 40 tbc
[udp @ 0000004c84338500] 'circular_buffer_size' option was set but it is not sup
ported on this build (pthread support is required)
[udp @ 0000004c84338240] 'circular_buffer_size' option was set but it is not sup
ported on this build (pthread support is required)
Input #4, rtsp, from 'rtsp://admin:Instalador20@172.20.0.11':
  Metadata:
    title           : Media Presentation
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.317000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #4:0: Video: h264 (Main), yuv420p(progressive), 1280x720, 20 fps, 30
tbr, 90k tbn, 40 tbc
[udp @ 0000004c84337280] 'circular_buffer_size' option was set but it is not sup
ported on this build (pthread support is required)
[udp @ 0000004c84337700] 'circular_buffer_size' option was set but it is not sup
ported on this build (pthread support is required)
[rtsp @ 0000004c83bde580] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 0000004c83bde580] RTP: missed 516 packets
[h264 @ 0000004c842f9140] error while decoding MB 105 5, bytestream -61
[h264 @ 0000004c842f9140] concealing 7504 DC, 7504 AC, 7504 MV errors in I frame

Input #5, rtsp, from 'rtsp://admin:Instalador20@172.20.0.12':
  Metadata:
    title           : Media Presentation
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.365667, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #5:0: Video: h264 (Main), yuvj420p(pc, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080
 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 60 tbc
[udp @ 0000004c84338c00] 'circular_buffer_size' option was set but it is not sup
ported on this build (pthread support is required)
[udp @ 0000004c84337980] 'circular_buffer_size' option was set but it is not sup
ported on this build (pthread support is required)
[rtsp @ 0000004c84738000] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 0000004c84738000] RTP: missed 20 packets
[h264 @ 0000004c83b61a40] left block unavailable for requested intra mode
[h264 @ 0000004c83b61a40] error while decoding MB 0 30, bytestream 58745
[h264 @ 0000004c83b61a40] concealing 4609 DC, 4609 AC, 4609 MV errors in I frame

Input #6, rtsp, from 'rtsp://admin:Instalador20@172.20.0.13':
  Metadata:
    title           : Media Presentation
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.299667, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #6:0: Video: h264 (Main), yuvj420p(pc, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080
 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 60 tbc
[udp @ 0000004c84236a80] 'circular_buffer_size' option was set but it is not sup
ported on this build (pthread support is required)
[udp @ 0000004c84236fc0] 'circular_buffer_size' option was set but it is not sup
ported on this build (pthread support is required)
[rtsp @ 0000004c845794c0] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 0000004c845794c0] RTP: missed 394 packets
[h264 @ 0000004c83b61ec0] error while decoding MB 10 8, bytestream -5
[h264 @ 0000004c83b61ec0] concealing 7239 DC, 7239 AC, 7239 MV errors in I frame

[h264 @ 0000004c83b61ec0] Increasing reorder buffer to 1
Input #7, rtsp, from 'rtsp://admin:Instalador20@172.20.0.14':
  Metadata:
    title           : Media Presentation
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.299667, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #7:0: Video: h264 (Main), yuvj420p(pc, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080
 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 60 tbc
[udp @ 0000004c84237600] 'circular_buffer_size' option was set but it is not sup
ported on this build (pthread support is required)
[udp @ 0000004c842369c0] 'circular_buffer_size' option was set but it is not sup
ported on this build (pthread support is required)
Input #8, rtsp, from 'rtsp://admin:Instalador20@172.20.0.15':
  Metadata:
    title           : Media Presentation
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.199667, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #8:0: Video: h264 (Main), yuvj420p(pc, bt709, progressive), 1280x720,
 30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 60 tbc
[udp @ 0000004c84238240] 'circular_buffer_size' option was set but it is not sup
ported on this build (pthread support is required)
[udp @ 0000004c84237ec0] 'circular_buffer_size' option was set but it is not sup
ported on this build (pthread support is required)
Input #9, rtsp, from 'rtsp://admin:Instalador20@172.20.0.16':
  Metadata:
    title           : Media Presentation
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.200667, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #9:0: Video: h264 (Main), yuvj420p(pc, bt709, progressive), 1280x720,
 30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 60 tbc
File 'video.mp4' already exists. Overwrite? [y/N] y
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (h264) -> overlay:overlay
  Stream #1:0 (h264) -> overlay:overlay
  overlay -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[rtsp @ 0000004c83b4c240] Thread message queue blocking; consider raising the th
read_queue_size option (current value: 8)
[rtsp @ 0000004c8412a840] Thread message queue blocking; consider raising the th
read_queue_size option (current value: 8)
[libx264 @ 0000004c84576c00] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0000004c84576c00] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2
AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0000004c84576c00] profile High, level 5.0, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0000004c84576c00] 264 - core 158 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft
2003-2019 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1
:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_rang
e=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_
offset=-2 threads=22 lookahead_threads=3 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interl
aced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bia
s=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40
 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpm
ax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'video.mp4':
  Metadata:
    title           : Media Presentation
    encoder         : Lavf58.33.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 3840x720 [S
AR 1:1 DAR 16:3], q=-1--1, 25 fps, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.59.102 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
frame=   32 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=
[rtsp @ 0000004c8412a840] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 0000004c8412a840] RTP: missed 582 packets
[h264 @ 0000004c84e534c0] error while decoding MB 73 8, bytestream -12
[h264 @ 0000004c84e534c0] concealing 2936 DC, 2936 AC, 2936 MV errors in I frame

[h264 @ 0000004c84e56240] Increasing reorder buffer to 1
frame=   60 fps= 59 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=
rtsp://admin:Instalador20@172.20.0.8: corrupt decoded frame in stream 0
frame=   90 fps= 59 q=28.0 size=     256kB time=00:00:00.84 bitrate=2496.8kbits/
frame=  125 fps= 62 q=28.0 size=     512kB time=00:00:02.24 bitrate=1872.6kbits/
frame=  160 fps= 63 q=28.0 size=     512kB time=00:00:03.64 bitrate=1152.4kbits/
frame=  197 fps= 65 q=28.0 size=     768kB time=00:00:05.12 bitrate=1228.9kbits/
frame=  233 fps= 65 q=28.0 size=     768kB time=00:00:06.56 bitrate= 959.1kbits/
[h264 @ 0000004c84e514c0] error while decoding MB 72 36, bytestream -7
[h264 @ 0000004c84e514c0] concealing 697 DC, 697 AC, 697 MV errors in P frame
rtsp://admin:Instalador20@172.20.0.7: corrupt decoded frame in stream 0
frame=  277 fps= 68 q=28.0 size=    1024kB time=00:00:08.32 bitrate=1008.3kbits/
frame=  320 fps= 70 q=28.0 size=    1536kB time=00:00:10.04 bitrate=1253.3kbits/
frame=  367 fps= 72 q=28.0 size=    1536kB time=00:00:11.92 bitrate=1055.6kbits/
frame=  412 fps= 74 q=28.0 size=    1536kB time=00:00:13.72 bitrate= 917.1kbits/
frame=  457 fps= 75 q=28.0 size=    1536kB time=00:00:15.52 bitrate= 810.8kbits/
[rtsp @ 0000004c8412a840] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 0000004c8412a840] RTP: missed 54 packets
[h264 @ 0000004c84e56240] error while decoding MB 5 8, bytestream -16
[h264 @ 0000004c84e56240] concealing 3004 DC, 3004 AC, 3004 MV errors in I frame

rtsp://admin:Instalador20@172.20.0.8: corrupt decoded frame in stream 0
frame=  503 fps= 76 q=28.0 size=    1792kB time=00:00:17.36 bitrate= 845.6kbits/
frame=  533 fps= 75 q=28.0 size=    1792kB time=00:00:18.56 bitrate= 791.0kbits/
frame=  545 fps= 72 q=28.0 size=    1792kB time=00:00:19.04 bitrate= 771.0kbits/
frame=  558 fps= 69 q=28.0 size=    1792kB time=00:00:19.56 bitrate= 750.5kbits/
frame=  570 fps= 66 q=28.0 size=    2048kB time=00:00:20.04 bitrate= 837.2kbits/
frame=  583 fps= 64 q=28.0 size=    2048kB time=00:00:20.56 bitrate= 816.0kbits/
frame=  597 fps= 62 q=28.0 size=    2304kB time=00:00:21.12 bitrate= 893.7kbits/
frame=  609 fps= 60 q=28.0 size=    2304kB time=00:00:21.60 bitrate= 873.8kbits/
frame=  622 fps= 58 q=28.0 size=    2304kB time=00:00:22.12 bitrate= 853.3kbits/
frame=  634 fps= 57 q=28.0 size=    2304kB time=00:00:22.60 bitrate= 835.2kbits/
frame=  647 fps= 56 q=28.0 size=    2304kB time=00:00:23.12 bitrate= 816.4kbits/
frame=  659 fps= 54 q=28.0 size=    2304kB time=00:00:23.60 bitrate= 799.8kbits/
frame=  672 fps= 53 q=28.0 size=    2304kB time=00:00:24.12 bitrate= 782.5kbits/
frame=  684 fps= 52 q=28.0 size=    2304kB time=00:00:24.60 bitrate= 767.3kbits/
frame=  697 fps= 51 q=28.0 size=    2560kB time=00:00:25.12 bitrate= 834.9kbits/
frame=  709 fps= 50 q=28.0 size=    2560kB time=00:00:25.60 bitrate= 819.2kbits/
frame=  722 fps= 49 q=28.0 size=    2560kB time=00:00:26.12 bitrate= 802.9kbits/
frame=  734 fps= 48 q=28.0 size=    2560kB time=00:00:26.60 bitrate= 788.4kbits/
frame=  747 fps= 48 q=28.0 size=    2560kB time=00:00:27.12 bitrate= 773.3kbits/
frame=  760 fps= 47 q=28.0 size=    2560kB time=00:00:27.64 bitrate= 758.7kbits/
frame=  773 fps= 46 q=28.0 size=    2816kB time=00:00:28.16 bitrate= 819.2kbits/
frame=  785 fps= 46 q=28.0 size=    2816kB time=00:00:28.64 bitrate= 805.5kbits/
frame=  798 fps= 45 q=28.0 size=    2816kB time=00:00:29.16 bitrate= 791.1kbits/
frame=  810 fps= 44 q=28.0 size=    2816kB time=00:00:29.64 bitrate= 778.3kbits/
frame=  823 fps= 44 q=28.0 size=    3072kB time=00:00:30.16 bitrate= 834.4kbits/
frame=  836 fps= 43 q=28.0 size=    3072kB time=00:00:30.68 bitrate= 820.3kbits/
frame=  849 fps= 43 q=28.0 size=    3328kB time=00:00:31.20 bitrate= 873.8kbits/
frame=  861 fps= 43 q=28.0 size=    3328kB time=00:00:31.68 bitrate= 860.6kbits/
frame=  874 fps= 42 q=28.0 size=    3328kB time=00:00:32.20 bitrate= 846.7kbits/
frame=  886 fps= 42 q=28.0 size=    3328kB time=00:00:32.68 bitrate= 834.3kbits/
frame=  899 fps= 41 q=28.0 size=    3328kB time=00:00:33.20 bitrate= 821.2kbits/
frame=  912 fps= 41 q=28.0 size=    3328kB time=00:00:33.72 bitrate= 808.5kbits/
frame=  924 fps= 41 q=28.0 size=    3328kB time=00:00:34.20 bitrate= 797.2kbits/
[rtsp @ 0000004c84282040] Thread message queue blocking; consider raising the th
read_queue_size option (current value: 8)
[rtsp @ 0000004c843ab140] Thread message queue blocking; consider raising the th
read_queue_size option (current value: 8)
[rtsp @ 0000004c84513a80] Thread message queue blocking; consider raising the th
read_queue_size option (current value: 8)
[rtsp @ 0000004c83bde580] Thread message queue blocking; consider raising the th
read_queue_size option (current value: 8)
[rtsp @ 0000004c84738000] Thread message queue blocking; consider raising the th
read_queue_size option (current value: 8)
[rtsp @ 0000004c845794c0] Thread message queue blocking; consider raising the th
read_queue_size option (current value: 8)
[rtsp @ 0000004c84898740] Thread message queue blocking; consider raising the th
read_queue_size option (current value: 8)
[rtsp @ 0000004c8468c780] Thread message queue blocking; consider raising the th
read_queue_size option (current value: 8)
frame=  928 fps= 40 q=-1.0 Lsize=    3674kB time=00:00:37.00 bitrate= 813.5kbits
/s speed=1.58x
video:3663kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing
overhead: 0.321748%
[libx264 @ 0000004c84576c00] frame I:4     Avg QP:14.42  size:323261
[libx264 @ 0000004c84576c00] frame P:234   Avg QP:21.24  size:  9794
[libx264 @ 0000004c84576c00] frame B:690   Avg QP:31.64  size:   239
[libx264 @ 0000004c84576c00] consecutive B-frames:  0.9%  0.0%  0.0% 99.1%
[libx264 @ 0000004c84576c00] mb I  I16..4: 21.9% 27.1% 51.1%
[libx264 @ 0000004c84576c00] mb P  I16..4:  0.1%  0.3%  0.3%  P16..4:  4.1%  0.7
%  0.5%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:94.0%
[libx264 @ 0000004c84576c00] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8:  1.6%  0.0
%  0.0%  direct: 0.0%  skip:98.4%  L0:31.4% L1:68.4% BI: 0.2%
[libx264 @ 0000004c84576c00] 8x8 transform intra:32.1% inter:28.3%
[libx264 @ 0000004c84576c00] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 67.7% 36.8% 24.1% inter: 0
.8% 0.8% 0.1%
[libx264 @ 0000004c84576c00] i16 v,h,dc,p: 68%  8%  4% 19%
[libx264 @ 0000004c84576c00] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 27% 18% 37%  2%  2%
 3%  3%  3%  4%
[libx264 @ 0000004c84576c00] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 46% 24%  8%  3%  3%
 4%  4%  3%  4%
[libx264 @ 0000004c84576c00] i8c dc,h,v,p: 50% 24% 19%  7%
[libx264 @ 0000004c84576c00] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0000004c84576c00] ref P L0: 70.0% 17.3% 11.7%  0.9%
[libx264 @ 0000004c84576c00] ref B L0: 80.6% 18.9%  0.5%
[libx264 @ 0000004c84576c00] ref B L1: 92.7%  7.3%
[libx264 @ 0000004c84576c00] kb/s:808.14
Exiting normally, received signal 2.
```

Comment: please provide a text version of that console output, or at least a picture that isn't thumbnail sized and hard to read.

Comment: try to decode 16 concurrent streams by starting plain ffmpeg processes, without OpenCV. if that also fails, system resource limits are likely the cause.